# Making LinkedIn API request using Hammock .net web library

Tags: c#, api, rest, linkedin-api

I'm doing some integration with LinkedIn APIs using C# and the Hammock libray.

I'm stuck trying to use the messaging API... I get an error saying "Couldn't parse mailbox-item document: error: Unexpected end of file after null".

It seams that the POST content is going empty I don't know...

Here's my code:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();

client.Authority = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1";
client.Credentials = credentials;
//client.Method = WebMethod.Post;

byte[] msg = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(doc.OuterXml);
client.AddPostContent(msg);


RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Path = "/people/~/mailbox";
request.Method = WebMethod.Post;
//request.AddPostContent(msg);


RestResponse response = client.Request(request);
```

My xml (that goes in msg variable) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mailbox-item>
 <recipients>
  <recipient>
   <person path="/people/~" />
  </recipient>
 </recipients>
 <subject>teste</subject>
 <body>teste</body>
</mailbox-item>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line that adds the POST content is commented out!

Comment: Well that's one of my doubts... should I add the content to the client or the request? Right now I do it in the client.

Comment: It doesn't matter which; it's just a precedence thing, as they both inherit from the same base class. It's so you can set a "default" in client, but override it in a request.